# CakePHP: Escape single quotes within an implode function delimited with commas

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I have a routine in my controller that retrieves the values from a single database column and builds a quoted array out of them:

```
$suppliers=$this->Model->find('list',array('fields'=>array('Model.supplier', 'Model.supplier')));
$strSuppliers="'".implode("','", $suppliers)."'";
$this->set('suppliers', $strSuppliers);
```

$strSuppliers is then fed to a jQuery script that creates an auto-complete dropdown list in the "suppliers" field in my Edit view:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [<?php echo $suppliers ?>]; 
    $( "#MsrSupplier" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
   });
 });
</script>
```

The output of the variable is something like 'Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', etc.

This works fine, unless any of the retrieved values contain single quotes. 'Tom's', 'Dick', 'Harry' breaks the array, and I'm having difficulty understanding how to escape the single quotes so that my dropdown will continue to function when they're present. I've tried changing the delimiter and swapping single quotes for double quotes, like so:

```
$strSuppliers='"'.implode("','", $suppliers).'"';
```

But that didn't work. What else might I try here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for PHP to output a JSON string, and then look at [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for use in your jQuery.

Instead of using `implode()` to generate your string, use `json_encode()` and then have `JSON.parse()` decode that for use in whatever application you need.

**Edit:** Added some code for clarity:

```
$strSuppliers = json_encode($suppliers);
```

and then in your jQuery:

```
var jsonStr = '<?php echo $suppliers; ?>';
var availableTags = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

**EDIT 2:** As ndm pointed out in the comments, you can do this more cleanly by directly assigning the Javascript variable to the output of `json_encode()`:

```
var availableTags = <?php echo $suppliers; ?>;
```

Comment: That's one step more than necessary, you can simply assign the return value of `json_encode()` to a JS var.

Comment: Well that certainly got me some...  interesting output! When I change my code to reflect your suggestions and I inspect the field, I get the following error:  `Uncaught TypeError: this.source is not a function at a.(anonymous function).anonymous function)._search...` followed by a link to the jquery-ui file.

Comment: That could be a number of different things. I would try doing `console.log(availableTags)` to what your array is coming out like. I can help you troubleshoot in the PHP chatroom if you'd like

Comment: I would appreciate that. Thank you!